# Perfect Multicollinearity

Tags: multiple-regression, inference, regression-coefficients, multicollinearity, linear

If 2 independent variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ in a hypothetical linear regression model $y = \beta_0+\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \varepsilon$ are perfectly multicollinear, which of the 2 independent variables should I exclude from the model if it is given that $x_1=10 x_2$? It should somehow related to the unit of measurement in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are perfectly multicollinear it makes no difference which one you exclude. The actual coefficient that you obtain from the regression if you exclude $x_2$ will be 10 times compared to if you exclude $x_1$. But things like p-value and $R^2$ will be the same.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "unit of measurement in the model". If $x_1 = 10 x_2$ then $x_1$ and $x_2$ must have the same units of measurement.

Answer (score 0):

if $x_1=10x_2$, then your new beta is either 
($10β_1+β_2$) and the variable to use is $x_2$ 
or 
$β_1+\frac{β_2}{10}$) and the variable is $x_1$.

Like mentioned by oneloop, it really does not matter which one you eliminate, p-value and $R^2$ will remain the same.